# Override Appsettings.json configuration based on runtime values exploiting the standard IConfiguration behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, appsettings

I'm wondering if there's a way to exploit the standard IConfiguration, IOption override functionality to override appsettings configuration values based on per request evaluated data.

I have a multi tenant application and I'd like to have some common default configuration values for the whole platform but I'd like also to be able to override some of them per Tenant or even per "Division" inside each tenant.

I store the Tenant's and Division's configurations as Json in the database and I'd like to be able to merge/override the appsettings values with those in the db per request once resolved the tenant.

Obviously I can do it manually but I'm wondering if I can integrate and exploit the already working merging/override functionality of the standard asp.net core IConfiguration/IOption.

Comment: Not sure how it can be done, but I think [Named Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#named-options-support-using-iconfigurenamedoptions) is your way to go.

Comment: I don't think Named Options will work, they seems to be evaluated only at Startup as well, what I need is to merge the options at each request based on the current Tenant/Division

Comment: But why can't you evaluate options ahead of time for all tenants and then retrieve the correct one on demand?

Comment: didn't tought about this option, but anyway for this I need to implement my own merging algorithm as Tenants are dynamics and the configuration for each tenant is on the db. I was looking to exploit the merging that is automatically done by asp.net configuration.
But probably this is not possible because the Asp.Net Configuration is working only on startup as I understand

Comment: I don't think computing options on each request is a good idea because it will have a performance penalty. One solution I can think about is adding custom middleware that will retrieve required named options and store them in the `AsyncLocal` field of some kind of accessor. Then you will inject this accessor and retrieve the options similar to how it works in [`HttpContextAccessor`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/5e6099229ce0b4f1bdd7374107cb9bcf8693a3a8/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextAccessor.cs)

Comment: For the DB part, you can try to implement a [custom configuration source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-configuration-provider) to load config from DB, and if you can rice an event on config change, you can reload this configuration source. Check this link for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/change-tokens?view=aspnetcore-6.0